# Swift 3 Camera Won't Save

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to work on a custom camera. It is in it's infancy. i have used a couple of tutorials online but since recent changes the code is out of date. I have done my best to adjust it. However i have hit the following wall. When i am in the app, i can take the photo and view the photo library, however when i take the photo and select it, it does not appear, so when i hit the save button the app crashes out and the console reports a nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Any help on correcting this issue and getting the image to display in the UI for saving would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var pickedImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    }

    @IBAction func camerabuttonaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func photolibraryaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
        var chosenImage = UIImage()
        chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        pickedImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        pickedImage.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

    func saveNotice(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message: "Your picture was successfully saved.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage.image!, 0.6)
        let compressedJPEGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPEGImage!, nil, nil, nil)
        saveNotice()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Please Check this in your code storyBoard if you replace Code]

And reConnect the IBAction in storyboard to avoid any crash

Please Replace your code with below Code Saving and displaying image Working

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var pickedImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func camerabuttonaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
             imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func photolibraryaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
             imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
        var chosenImage = UIImage()
        chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        pickedImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        pickedImage.image = chosenImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

    func saveNotice(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message: "Your picture was successfully saved.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage.image!, 0.6)
        let compressedJPEGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPEGImage!, nil, nil, nil)
        saveNotice()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I can see the image now however when i click save the app crashes and closes. This is the code i get in the debug console: **ViewController savebuttonaction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157e0eca0
2017-07-10 23:00:28.511302+0100 Cam Stats[1983:612888] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Cam_Stats.ViewController savebuttonaction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157e0eca0' **

Comment: please check if that button is connected to the ibaction you had provided because at my end this code is working fine I checked on device and simulator too. and if you still facing the same issue delete ibAction of button from storyboard and reconnect to ibaction made. if still error occur I will share my project with you and also check for keys in info.plist for camera and gallery access NscameraUsage and NsPhotoLibrary

Comment: Thank you, i checked all again and reran but the issue still appears. It loads the AppDelagate.swift and loads the following line in highlighted **redclass AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {** not sure where the issue is?

Comment: Sure, what is the best way to do this? Which file do you need?

Comment: Don't worry, i checked the IBA Action again and it loaded two actions for the view controller. All sorted and working! Thank you